# How to get array when match the value, then use it

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have a page just to store datas that I need using Advanced Custom Field in WordPress and I named it **page_categories-animation.php**

In my **index.php**, I wrote this

```
// get post id from page feature animation categories
$anim_id = url_to_postid('feature-animation-categories');
// get all the data from it
$variable = get_field('animCategory', $anim_id);

print_r($variable);
```

The output of **$variable** is like this (actually its have 20 arrays but I use 2 arrays just so easy to understand)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Coffee Machines
            [categoryId] => 12
            [animateTitle] => Better ways to cleaner dishes.
            [animateIcon] => 
            [animateLink] => http://google.com
            [animateBG] => 
            [fram1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 315
                    [id] => 315
                    [title] => coffee-frame1
                    [filename] => coffee-frame1.png
                )

            [fram2] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 316
                    [id] => 316
                    [title] => coffee-frame2
                    [filename] => coffee-frame2.png
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Cooking & Baking
            [categoryId] => 13
            [animateTitle] => Better ways to cleaner dishes.
            [animateIcon] => 
            [animateLink] => http://google.com
            [animateBG] => 
            [fram1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 318
                    [id] => 318
                    [title] => cookie-frame1
                    [filename] => cookie-frame1.png
                )

            [fram2] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 319
                    [id] => 319
                    [title] => cookie-frame2
                    [filename] => cookie-frame2.png
                )
        )
)
```

My question is : How I can use the array that match the value, in this case just assume we already have **categoryId 13** and i want to grab the array which have **categoryId 13** and use it.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the result? why not simply loop through the $variable array and filter the result?

Comment: @silver i just want the data and apply it in my div, nothing fancy or complicated i think.  im not good enough using php, only this idea is popup in my head T_T , i think this is easier for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
$use_array = [];

foreach($variable as $v) // loop through your array of data
{
    if($v['categoryId'] == 13) // look for categoryId = 13
    {
        $use_array = $v; // save this array for later use
        break; // quit looping to save processing time and resources
    }
}

print_r($use_array); // this will be your array with categoryId = 13
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply just filter your array like so

http://ideone.com/cingTP

**Your array**

```
$variable = [
    "0" => [
        "category_name" => 'Coffee Machines',
        "categoryId" => 12,
        "animateTitle" => 'Better ways to cleaner dishes.',
        "animateIcon" => '',
        "animateLink" => 'http://google.com',
        "animateBG" => "",
        "fram1" => [
            "ID" => 315,
            "id" => 315,
            "title" => 'coffee-frame1',
            "filename" => 'coffee-frame1.png',
        ],
        "fram2" => [
            "ID" => 316,
            "id" => 316,
            "title" => 'coffee-frame2',
            "filename" => 'coffee-frame2.png',
        ]
    ],
    "1" => [
        "category_name" => 'Cooking & Baking',
        "categoryId" => 13,
        "animateTitle" => 'Better ways to cleaner dishes.',
        "animateIcon" => '',
        "animateLink" => 'http://google.com',
        "animateBG" => '',
        "fram1" => [
            "ID" => 318,
            "id" => 318,
            "title" => 'cookie-frame1',
            "filename" => 'cookie-frame1.png',
        ],
        "fram2" => [
            "ID" => 319,
            "id" => 319,
            "title" => 'cookie-frame2',
            "filename" => 'cookie-frame2.png',
        ]
    ]
];
```

**Solution**

```
$result = array_filter($variable, function($item) {
    return $item['categoryId'] == 13;
});

print_r($result);
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt works for me, this return empty array

Comment: I transformed your output array into PHP array and then provided this answer. :) Updated my answer so take a look

Comment: copy paste your php array and your code, its still empty

Comment: I am getting this output. Array ( [1] => Array ( [category_name] => Cooking & Baking [categoryId] => 13 [animateTitle] => Better ways to cleaner dishes. [animateIcon] => [animateLink] => http://google.com [animateBG] => [fram1] => Array ( [ID] => 318 [id] => 318 [title] => cookie-frame1 [filename] => cookie-frame1.png ) [fram2] => Array ( [ID] => 319 [id] => 319 [title] => cookie-frame2 [filename] => cookie-frame2.png ) ) )

Comment: i dont know what happen but your sollution doesnt works here, maybe theres some function in my functions.php that broken your code

Comment: Hmm that might be the case. However, i've made a fiddle for you to test my solution. http://ideone.com/cingTP

Comment: @caberg this solution works but you need a minimum of PHP 5.3.0 in order to use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: The only issue with this solution is that if there are multiple entries with `categoryId = 13` then it will return multiple results. @caberg With this solution you need to use `print_r($result[1]);`

Comment: `print_r(array_slice($result, 0, 1));` would also work

Comment: i have some crap PHP server so its doesnt works here.  its return nothing ^_^

Comment: @MonkeyZeus if expected is matched category array then why choose  only the first result? It was not in the requirement thats why i choose array_filter to grab all arrays having category of 13 :)